# Decomposing operators into the sum of a quasinilpotent and something else

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I seem to remember some result of the following sort:

> **Alleged Theorem.** Every bounded operator on a separable complex Hilbert space can be decomposed as the sum of a normal operator and a quasinilpotent operator.

However, I can't remember if this is the correct statement of the result. Is the theorem as stated obviously true? obviously false? Is there a related result with "normal" replaced by some other class of operators?

I googled it and found [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123690901222%22Triangular%20form%20for%20bounded%20operators%22), which is similar to the above stated theorem, but it places spectral restrictions on the class of bounded operators for which it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you thinking of the Weyl-von Neumann-Berg Theorem?

Every normal operator $N$ on a separable Hilbert space can be decomposed as $N=D+K$, the sum of a a diagonal normal operator $D$ and a compact operator $K$?

Or the Brown-Douglas-Fillmore Theorem?

An operator $T \in B(H)$ is a compact perturbation of a normal operator if and only if $T$ is essentially normal and the Fredholm index $\operatorname{ind} (T-\lambda)=0$ for every $\lambda$ not in the essential spectrum of $T$.

See [this Encyclopedia of Mathematics page for further details](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Brown-Douglas-Fillmore_theory) .

Or a theorem due to West?

Every Riesz operator is the sum of a quasinilpotent operator and a compact operator.

Comment: No, I know all of these. I think I was living in some sort of fantasy world and the result just doesn't exist. Thanks though. I'm going to give it another day or two just in case someone finds something, but barring that I'll accept your answer.